# Ordered Linked List vs B-Tree

Tags: database, indexing, b-tree

If you have a b+ tree as an index, then this seems to be very similar to a ordered linked list. But the ordered linked list seem to have some advantages, such as not having to navigate a tree structure and also not having to rebuild nodes when they get full, and not having to rebuild the tree when it gets unballanced.

Can anyone answer what is the reason for using a b-tree rather than an ordered linked list?

Comment: I think the question makes much more sense if you compare with a random access list and not with a linked list. Because linked list require you to traverse them to access an element which makes them O(n) searchable even if they are sorted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some research and paper reading I found the answer.

In order to cope with large amounts of data such as millions of records, indexes have to be organised into clusters. A cluster is a continuous group of sectors on a disk that can be read into memory quickly. These are usually about 4096 bytes long.

If we organise our index so that each of these clusters contains a ordered list of indexes which point to data on a disk (a data cluster),  we can have a ordered list index.

So, if we are looking for a specific record, how do we know which cluster it is on? We perform  a binary search to find the cluster in question [O(log n)].

However, to do a binary search we need to know the range of values in each data cluster, so we need meta-data that says the min and max value of each cluster and where that cluster is. This is great. Except if each data cluster contains 100 indexes, and our meta data cluster also contains 100 indexes then we can only access 100 data clusters. Which equates to 10 000 records (100 X 100).

Well that’s not enough. Lets add another meta-data cluster and we can now access 1 000 000 records. So how do we know which one of the three meta-data clusters we need to query in order to find our target data cluster. We could search them one after the other, but that doesn’t scale, and its O(n/2) on average. So I add another meta-meta-data cluster to indicate which one of the three meta-data clusters I should query to find the target data cluster.  Now I have a tree!

So that’s why databases use trees. It’s not the speed, it’s the size of the indexes and the need to have indexes referencing other indexes. What I have described above is a B+Tree – child nodes contain references to other child nodes or leaf nodes, and leaf nodes contain references to data on disk.

Phew!

Answer (score 2):

There are many difference in the characteristics, but I emphasize search time.

While search is **O(log N) time in b+ tree** it is **O(n) time in linked list**, even if it is sorted.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree

Comment: This is not the case. If the list is ordered and you know the number of elements in it (which is easy with a bit of meta data) then you can use a binary search which is O(log n) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search 

Also, each node in a tree requires you to know the min and max values and thus once you've found your target node, you still have to perform a binary search on that node anyway. Hence a ordered list should be faster (no node navigation plus the re-building etc).

Comment: I also thought about binary search. I have serious doubts whether is is feasible on linked lists (even if ordered). I concluded, somehow it could be implemented but that implementation would rely on how  the list itself was implemented and represented in the memory. Can you tell me how you would get the middle element without iterating through half of the elements?

Comment: middleElement = list[listLength-1 / 2]; // -1 is there depending what you call the middle element where listLength is even

See http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Binary_search for fuller algorithms.

However, the implementation is not important. The important issue is can it be faster than a B-Tree taking into account all the other maintenance issues that need to take place (re-balancing etc). Or am I missing something?

Comment: Adam, here's the thing with `middleElement = list[listLength-1 / 2];`  Operations that index into the linked list will traverse the list from the beginning or the end. That means positional access, like `list[listLength-1 / 2]` requires linear time in a linked list as opposed to constant time in an array. That is why binary search on a linked list is O(n) instead of O(log n).

Comment: Ah? If you have a list and access it by index, you don't do any traversing - you access the element directly. That's the whole point of index access. That is why binary search is log-n. Not linear.

Comment: @Adam Davies, what you are talking about is a "normal " list that allows random access. In a *linked* list, there is NO random access and that's why even in a sorted linked list, search is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

In a binary search tree, O(log n) search time is the average case. In the worst case, when the tree is totally unbalanced and resembles a linked list, search needs O(n) time.

Comment: Items in a sorted lists can be found via a binary search. So it is O(log n). Sorry mate, but that is the definition of a binary search. For example http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,%20T). Just to be clear, RandomAccess list is a list whose elements can be access by any random value of an index (so long at the value is within range)

Comment: From the docs you've linked: binary search "runs in log(n) time for a "random access" list (which provides near-constant-time positional access). If the specified list does not implement the RandomAccess interface and is large, this method will do an iterator-based binary search that performs O(n) link traversals and O(log n) element comparisons." Think about it: Java [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) **DOES NOT** implement [RandomAccess](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html) interface.

Comment: Not in java but there is no reason why it can't be made to